# Package download problem

Tags: apt, package-management

---

Whenever I try to install the `vim` package the following error appears. What should I do?

```
Failed to fetch  http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_7.3.547-4ubuntu1.1_all.deb
 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch  http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.3.547-4ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
 404  Not Found 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: That package version is for Ubuntu 12.10 (see [LP](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/2:7.3.547-4ubuntu1.1)). 12.10 has reached end-of-life. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release on instructions for upgrading.

Comment: Was there a network connectivity issue when this was attempted?  If so, that needed to be checked and usually then running apt-get update would resolve the matter like the error indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try clear vim and install again:

```
sudo apt-get remove vim-common
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get purge
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vim
```